# How to fetch data from database inside the for loop in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

fetching data inside the for loop using pool query in node js output values are correct but not at the correct position.
Here is my code.

```
for(var k=0; k < mdmid_array_implode_array_st.length; k++){
var mdmid_arr=mdmid_array_implode_array_st[k];
pool.query("select sum(cnt_deal_amt) as cnt_deal_amt from crm_clients_feedback_log where cnt_mdm_id IN ("+mdmid_arr+") ORDER BY cnt_mdm_id ASC",function(dealerr,dealrslt){
dealrslt_sa=dealrslt[0].cnt_deal_amt;
console.log(dealrslt);
})
}

OUtPUT:
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 512529 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 33000 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 1000 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 43600 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 0 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 0 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 9500 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 11500 } ]
```

output result values are not at correct position also every time position changed when refreshing the page.

```
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 512529 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 43600 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 0 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 9500 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 33000 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 0 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 1000 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: 11500 } ]
[ RowDataPacket { cnt_deal_amt: null } ]
```

Comment: Perform the sort operation on mdmid_array_implode_array_st.sort() and check again.

Comment: thankq chetan for reply, first time give correct position but when refreshing the page position has been changed

Comment: have you checked mdmid_array_implode_array_st remains same in both condition? (1st time and after refreshing page)

Comment: yes, mdmid_array_implode_array_st remains same in both condition

Answer (score 0):

Node js is asynchronous and you cannot preserve order while executing loops.Node loops behaves differently from other languages.
I would suggest you an alternative solution using callbacks to preserve order.

```
var k = 0;
function query(cb) {
    var mdmid_arr= mdmid_array_implode_array_st[k];
    var my_query = "select sum(cnt_deal_amt) as cnt_deal_amt from crm_clients_feedback_log where cnt_mdm_id IN ("+mdmid_arr+") ORDER BY cnt_mdm_id ASC";
    pool.query(my_query,cb);
}

var result = function(dealerr,dealrslt){
    dealrslt_sa=dealrslt[0].cnt_deal_amt;
    console.log(dealrslt);
    k ++;
    if(k < mdmid_array_implode_array_st.length) {
        setTimeOut(query,0,result);
    }   
}

query(result);
```

Comment: yes, its working thankq @vinoth, will you please let me know one more thing, how we use multiple queries in aysnc function

Comment: Take a look at [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) `async.waterfall` may suit your need.

Comment: one more question how we send this result in ejs template

Comment: use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs Accept the answer if your issue is solved.

Comment: how we get function result value in variable?? or i want above output result in variable

Answer (score 0):

This can be a best approach to deal such kind of tasks, Use Promise and async-await...

```js
 var counter = 0;
 const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
 mdmid_array_implode_array_st.forEach(async (num) => {
    await waitFor(50);
    console.log(num);
    /**STARTput whatevever want here... WRITE YOUR QUERY, I just copypasted your code, have not checked yet...**/
    var mdmid_arr=mdmid_array_implode_array_st[counter];
    pool.query("select sum(cnt_deal_amt) as cnt_deal_amt from crm_clients_feedback_log 
    where cnt_mdm_id IN ("+mdmid_arr+") ORDER BY cnt_mdm_id 
    ASC",function(dealerr,dealrslt){
            dealrslt_sa=dealrslt[0].cnt_deal_amt;
            console.log(dealrslt);
    });
    //END************************************
    counter++;
  });
```

P.S. This was the best approach for me, but you're getting null values, please have focus on sql query, but I recommend **use promise and async-await** with -->forEach<-- instead directly applying -->for<-- loop.